# Calculate percentage of vector point attributes within a polygon QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

I have a vector point layer with an attribute `Customer` with boolean values `true` and `false`. I want to aggregate this data by polygons, such that for a given polygon, it shows that `Customer` is XX% `true` and YY% `false`. I can't achieve this with join attributes by location (summary); I can only get `Customer_COUNT` from this.

Attached an example for reference -- I basically want to get the % blue and green points within a polygon.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use field calculator with `overlay_contains()` (or eventually `overlay_intersects()` depending on your needs) expression on your polygons for this. To get the count for each category simply set a filter to your needs, for example:

```
array_length(overlay_contains('points',$id,filter:="cat"=0))
```

respectively for the other category

```
array_length(overlay_contains('points',$id,filter:="cat"=1))
```

Then calculate the percentage from these. So all in one:

```
array_length(overlay_contains('points',$id,filter:="cat"=1))
/
array_length(overlay_contains('points',$id))
```

Just replace `points` with the name of your points layer and `"cat"=1` with your field containing the category and the desired value of this category.

Answer (score 7):

Try this expression in the polygon layer:

```
with_variable(
    'values',
    overlay_contains('point layer name/id', "Customer"), -- replace here with your values
    with_variable(
        'total',
        100 / array_length(@values),
        format(
            '%1% true, %2% false', -- output will look like ##% true, ##% false.
            @total * array_count(@values, true), -- quote true if your field in the point layer is not boolean or is string
            @total * array_count(@values, false) -- same as above
        )
    )
)
```

you can control the format of the result modifying this line (`'%1% true, %2% false'`) as explained [here](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#format), for example: `'true: %1%, false: %2%'` will look like `true: ##%, false: ##%`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "**Count Features in Features by Category**" from [ProcessX Plug-In](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/) for this usecase.

Choose your polygons as *Source-Layer*, your points as *Overlay-Layer*, add the field containing your Customer as *Category-Expression*. As *desired output structure* I assume you want to choose *Create a field for each category*. Adjust the other settings if needed as well.

[image]

This will produce a copy of your polygon layer with two new fields added: Customer_True and Customer_False. Then use field calculator to calculate the percentage out of these.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of that Plug-In.*